# How to create thread with template member function of a template object in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, syntax, constructor

I am creating threadsafe list and i got a problem with calling thread constructor.
I got a template class

```
template <typename T>
class mylist{...}
```

that stores nodes with T data and `mylist` got member function defined like this

```
template <typename FUNC>
void for_each(FUNC f){...}
```

that calls f() for every T data in the list.
I also got function

```
template<typename T> 
void show(T data) 
{cout<<data<<", ";}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make thread and pass this function to it.
I tried like this (`mylist`is a class name,`multithreadlist`is an object of `mylist<size_t>`

```
std::thread t1(&mylist<size_t>::for_each<void(*)(size_t)>, &multithreadlist, show<size_t>);
```

and i get C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)' and C2672 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

Comment: I can not reproduce the error with MSVC, Clang or GCC. Can you post an MCVE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std thread call template member function of template class: compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617860/std-thread-call-template-member-function-of-template-class-compiler-error)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to not bother with [member] function pointers but to rather just use a lambda expression with appropriate captures:

```
std::thread t([&](){
        multithreadlist.for_each([](auto&& data){ show(data); })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem.  The code below works as expected in

- Clang 3.8 and 5.0
- GCC 5.4.1 and 7.1.0

Nevertheless, I would prefer the solution in the other answer myself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class mylist
{
  std::vector<T> m_list;
public:
  mylist(int n) : m_list(n)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      m_list[i] = i;
  }

  template < typename FUNC >
  void for_each(FUNC f)
  {
    for (auto const& p : m_list)
      f(p);
  }
};

template<typename T> 
void show(T data)
{
  std::cout << data << ", ";
}

int main()
{
  mylist<size_t> multithreadlist{5};
  std::thread t1(&mylist<size_t>::for_each<void(*)(size_t)>, multithreadlist, show<size_t>);
  t1.join();
}
```