# starting thread with member function having arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pthreads, pointer-to-member

I want to create a `std::thread` with member function *callReverse* and 2 other of class *threadedName*.
It's clear how to do it for function taking no arguments and returning void from this StackOverflow question [start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)
What is the correct way of doing the same for function taking arguments?
Can this be used for functions returning some non-void values?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
class threadedName
{
    // class body
    void callPermute()
    {  // function body 
    }
    void callReverse(char s[])
    {  // function body  
    }
    void callRearrange(char s[])
    { // function body  
    }
};
int main()
{
    threadedName ob;
    // doing something

    thread td1(&threadedName::reverseWords, &ob);
    thread td2(&threadedName::callPermute, &ob);
    thread td3(&threadedName::callRearrange, &ob);

    td3.join();
    td2.join();
    td1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to pass arguments to callReverse() and callRearrange

Comment: Stop doing: [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: related or an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501221/create-a-thread-over-a-templated-member-function/66501547